# How can I reuse anonymous properties already computed

Tags: c#, linq

I use a function to sum some fields but I have to use them also in a function, but I worried they are been computed twice. I am afraid this can cause a bad performance in the future.

```
var a = dataTable.AsEnumerable();
var test = new
           {
               contadorSolucao = a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorSolucao")),
               contadorAssunto = a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorAssunto")),
               contadorAbertura = a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorAbertura")),
               contadorMaquinas = a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorMaquinas")),
               contadorChamados = a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorChamados")),                                               

                // How can I reuse these fields above (contadorSolucao, contadorAssunto...) instead of below?
                // I suppose these fiels are been recalculated twice. How can I avoid this?
                porcentagemSolucao = MyFunction(a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorSolucao")),
                                                        a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorMaquinas")),
                                                        a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorAssunto")), 
                                                        a.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("ContadorNaoPodemSolucaoRemota")))

                /* This don't work
                porcentagemSolucao = MyFunction(contadorSolucao, contadorAssunto, contadorAbertura, contadorMaquinas, contadorChamados)
                */
           };
```

Comment: Create additional anonymous object with those calculated properties  together with orignal data and make yet another `Select` or whatever..

Comment: Does it have to be an anonymous object? Create a concrete class to handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values most certainly will be computed twice, as you've shown the code.  You'll need to do something to compute the values, store them somewhere, and then re-use them from several locations.

The simplest option here is likely to store each of the sums in local variables.  If you really need this anonymous type then you can create it based on those locals.

Comment: Tks! I did this before but I thought I could reuse them within the same expression but if is not possible I will follow your suggestion ;)